# Why is this error appearing?

Tags: python-3.x, system, message, attributeerror, encoder

> AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'encode'

I'm trying to make a text to code converter as an example for an assignment and this is some code based off of some I found in my research,

```
import binascii

text = input('Message Input: ')

data = binascii.b2a_base64.encode(text)
text = binascii.a2b_base64.encode(data)
print (text), "<=>", repr(data)

data = binascii.b2a_uu(text)
text = binascii.a2b_uu(data)
print (text), "<=>", repr(data)

data = binascii.b2a_hqx(text)
text = binascii.a2b_hqx(data)
print (text), "<=>", repr(data)
```

can anyone help me get it working? it's supposed to take an input in and then convert it into hex and others and display those...
I am using Python 3.6 but I am also a little out of practice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR:

```
data = binascii.b2a_base64(text.encode())
text = binascii.a2b_base64(data).decode()
print (text, "<=>", repr(data))
```

---

You've hit on a common problem in the Python3 - str object vs bytes object. The `bytes` object contains sequence of bytes. One byte can contain any number from 0 to 255. Usually those number are translated through the ASCII table into a characters like english letters. Usually in the Python you should use bytes for working with binary data.

On the other hand the `str` object contains sequence of code points. One code point usually represent one character printed on your screen when you call `print`. Internally it is sequence of bytes so the Chinese symbol `的` is internally saved as 3 bytes long sequence.

Now to the your problem. The function requires as input the `bytes` object but you've got a `str` object from the function `input`. To convert `str` into `bytes` you have to call `str.encode()` method on the `str` object.

```
data = binascii.b2a_base64(text.encode())
```

Your original call `binascii.b2a_base64.encode(text)` means call method `encode` of the object `binascii.b2a_base64` with parameter `text`.

The function `binascii.b2a_base64` returns `bytes` contains original input encoded with the base64 algorithms. Now to get back the original `str` from encoded data you have to call this:

```
# Take base64 encoded data and return it decoded as bytes object
decoded_data = binascii.a2b_base64(data) 
# Convert bytes object into str
text = decoded_data.decode()
```

It can be written as one line

```
decoded_data = binascii.a2b_base64(data).decode()
```

---

WARNING: Your call of `print` is invalid for Python 3 (it will work only in the python console)